# Windows key shortcuts - ctrl shift end

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I use the Ctrl + Shift + End all the time, but inexplicably recently, it keeps failing to work. Once it stops working, I have to change language, sign out, change back to US and sign in again. It's driving my nuts, any ideas on what is happening?

Windows 10, every app I use

Answer (score 1):

I use this shortcut a lot in SQLServer and Notepad ++...

I found a solution. Well, for me it solved!
In my case, the problem is caused when the Opera browser is open, even if minimized. Then Ctrl + Shift + End / Home doesn't work on any text file, Excel, SQL ...

The explanation is in this post:

[Opera Bug](https://www.askvg.com/opera-bug-fix-ctrlshifthome-and-ctrlshiftend-hotkeys-stopped-working-in-text-editors/)